# JQuery Ajax complete function executes right away

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a JQuery Ajax function which executes a php script which deletes some items in a MySql database. This ajax call is made whenever the user clicks a certain button. I want the page to reload when the call is complete and the deleted items not to be displayed. However, the 'complete' feature seems to execute before the php script is complete. Hence, the page reloads without deleting the items in the database. There is no form involved, just a button. How can I fix this?

```
<button id="deleteButton">Delete</button>


$('#deleteButton').click(function(){

   $.ajax({
      url:'clearDatabase.php',
      dataType:"json",
      data:{data:data},       
      type:'POST',      
      success:function(data){       
           if(data=="0"){
              alert("stuff deleted");
           }
      },    
      complete: function(XMLHttpRequest, status) {            
                    location.reload();
      }
   });  


});
```

Comment: What does the markup for the button look like? If it's not explicitly given a type to make it not be a "submit" button, then the problem is that the form is being submitted.

Comment: There's probably a problem with your PHP script. Have checked if it works if you manually send the request?

Comment: Where is `data` at `data:{data:data}` defined? Why is argument at `complete` referencing a function: `XMLHttpRequest`?

Comment: This is what a regular form, without any javascript, does ?

Comment: There is no form involved, just a button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your button is

```
<button id='deleteButton' >Click</button>

$('#deleteButton').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();// for not publish form

   $.ajax({
     url:'clearDatabase.php',
     dataType:"json",
     data:{data:data},       
     type:'POST',      
     success:function(data){       
       if(data=="0"){
          alert("stuff deleted");
          location.reload();//here you reload the page after the user close the alert
       }
  },    
  complete: function(XMLHttpRequest, status) {            
                location.reload();
  }
  });  


});
```

Comment: A proper written explanation would help. This is a likely problem/solution but also assumes that a form is involved

Answer (score 0):

Why do have you to use ajax if you want to reload page? Just turn your button into a tag:

```
<a href="clearDatabase.php?data=data">Click</a>
```

In `clearDatabase.php`:

```
//delete some items in databse
//then redirect to your page again
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work. I changed `location.reload`to `window.location=window.location`. I am relatively new to Ajax and I don't know why this works. If someone can shed some light as to why, it would be great.